# android toolbar and bottom bar overlapping recycler view in fragment container view

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, mobile, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to use RecyclerView along with custom toolbar and bottom bar but both is overlapping RecyclerView even though I have used constraintTop_toBottomOf and `constraintBottom_toTopOf` in my xml file.

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".ui.FeedFragment">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:title="@string/feed"
            />

        <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
            android:id="@+id/fragmentContainerView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:defaultNavHost="true"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_map" />

        <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_feed" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

Comment: It doesn't appear in the Recyclerview code?

Comment: It looks between toolbar and bottom bar in fragment screen which contains recyclerview code. But I still have the issue when I run the code on emulator

Answer (score 0):

You missing the constraint id for bottomNavigation and Toolbar
,
add             `app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/fragmentContainerView"` in your `toolbar` and add             `app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/fragmentContainerView"` at Bottomnavigation

Conclusion:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <layout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/fragmentContainerView"
            app:title="@string/feed"
            />

        <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
            android:id="@+id/fragmentContainerView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:defaultNavHost="true"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_map" />

        <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_feed"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/fragmentContainerView"
            />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </layout>
```

Comment: make sense but didn't worked for me. In android studio recycler view looks as it should be but when I run the app on emulator still overlapping

Answer (score 0):

When I double-checked the navigation graph, I noticed that the NavHost was missing in the XML, even though it was supposed to be there. I resolved the issue by removing and re-adding the fragment container view in the XML of the main activity.